# handling multiple identical messages in aws sqs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an architecture where a customer will upload a file or set of files to process to S3, the files are then moved (and untarred/zipped/etc) to a more appropriate S3 bucket, then a message will be placed in SQS from the lambda to be picked up by a compute engine.  In most cases, only one message per customer request is generated.  However, there might be a case where the customer will load say 200 images to the same request (all 200 images are slices from a single 3D image) one at a time.  This will generate 200 lambda calls and 200 messages.  My compute engine can process the same request multiple times without a problem, but I would like to avoid processing the same request 200+ times (each such process takes > 5mins on a large ec2 instance).

Is there a way working within the amazon tools to either coalesce messages in a queue having the same message body to a single message? Or to peek into a queue for a message having a specific message body?

The only thing I can think to do is have a "special" file in my destination S3 bucket that records the last time a lambda put this message in the queue, but the issue with that is, say the first image slice comes in and I put in the queue "Do this guy", 50 more images come in and I notice that the "special" file is there,  the message is picked up and processing starts, the rest of the images come in, then processing finishes and fails due to only 50 out of 60 needed images, but there are no pending messages in the queue because I blocked them all...

Or, I just suck it up and let the compute run for 200 times, fail quickly ~199 times, then succeed 1 (or more) times...

Comment: Can you store a hash of the message somewhere such that the store could be checked to see if the message with that hash has been processed? The check could be done before queuing or immediately after consuming from the queue. If so, would that provide a faster way to identify a message that has already been processed?

Comment: @jbird  I could just store the hash in an s3 bucket and just query if the s3 key exists, but I think that is just putting a round peg in a square hole.  My SQS consumers should be able to handle receiving the same message more than once, or I am just fighting what SQS was designed for.  Maybe there just is no clean solution

Comment: Agreed, especially since per the SQS docs there is no guarantee that SQS won't deliver a duplicate message and your system should always be able to handle duplicate messages. As long as your "fail quickly" isn't too burdensome what you have might be most efficient.